# Program to test resources used in browser sessions

Tags: cross-browser-testing

I've made a web-application and want to know how many resources are used for different operations in browser. Could you tell me some software.
I want to know it for IE, Chrome and any others - Memory, CPU, graph in time for every browser.

Comment: For chrome check the task manager: http://blog.laptopmag.com/how-to-use-chromes-built-in-task-manager

Answer (score 1):

Windows comes with an app called [Windows Performance Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749249.aspx).

You can set up monitors by process (each browser/tab will have it's own process). So long as the tab is open you can set it up to be monitored. You can track CPU usage, memory, all kinds of stuff. It also has charts to visualize your metrics over time.

Comment: Could youtell please how to do it? Bacuse when i opened it i only saw common graphics for pc and no configuration where i can choose a process

Comment: The link I provided has a how to use section. Check the navigation on the left side of the page.

Answer (score 1):

As well as the windows performance monitor, all the browsers come with developer tools which include a fair amount of monitoring, especially of load times.

If you combine perfmon for CPU and memory use with the browser dev tools for load times, you should have everything you need.